# Removing Rows that Are Exclusively NA

Tags: r, dataframe, na

Currently I have data that looks like this (just with significantly more NA filled columns and significantly more rows that are exclusively NAs):

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | NA |
| Texas | Oklahoma | NA |
| NA | Florida | Florida |
| NA | NA | NA |

I'd like for it to look like this

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Texas | Oklahoma | NA |
| NA | Florida | Florida |

I don't want to get rid of all rows that have an NA value, I just want to get rid of all rows that have nothing but NA values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: data[complete.cases(data), ]

Answer (score 1):

You can use janitor package:

```
janitor::remove_empty(dat, which = "rows")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of rows that contain only `NA` but keep rows that have some `NA` values you could combine `is.na` and `rowSums`

```
dat <- dat[rowSums(!is.na(dat)) > 0, ]
```

`is.na` will return a `TRUE` or `FALSE` which will be treated as `1` and `0`  for the `rowSums`. Any row with a value that is not `NA` will have a sum greater than 0.

Comment: or you can use janitor package       `janitor::remove_empty(dat, which = "rows")`

Comment: @Bloxx that uses `is.na` and `rowSums` just inside another package you have to install.

Comment: you are right. however, janitor package is very useful with data cleaning. Also with cleaning column names.

Comment: @Bloxx, you could post that as an answer ...